# How would one store the result of filtering a vector inside another vector without copying

Tags: c++, stdvector

In C++: Let's say I have a vector `const std:vector<MyStruct>` that (and its elements) won'tt be modified anymore. Now I want to filter this vector based on some predicate and store the result in some object, because I'd like to iterate over this subset of elements frequently.

Is there a good way to avoid copying `MyStructs` from the vector into the another vector and how would this be done?

Comment: It depends on how your application will work. Please make a [mcve]. So we can have something concrete to talk about.

Comment: `std::reference_wrapper`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done even with plain STL, using few standard types, [`reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) being one particularly important:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> cv{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> fv;
    std::copy_if(cv.begin(), cv.end(), std::back_inserter(fv)
        , [](int x){ return x % 2; });
    for(auto const &v: fv) std::cout << v << '\n';
    std::cout << "-----\n";
    cv[3] = 42;
    for(auto const &v: fv) std::cout << v << '\n';
}
```

```bash
$ g++ meow.cpp && ./a.out 
1
3
5
-----
1
42
5
```

Note how changes in `cv` reflect in `fv`. `fv` stores but references to the original elements, namely, to odd-valued elements of `cv`, so no copies are performed.